# Loop through all the rows of query results

Tags: php, loops

I display results from the table `users`:

```
 <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Name:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
               <?php if(!$row['name']==NULL){echo $row['name'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='name' value='<?php echo $row['name'];?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Gender:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['gender']==NULL){echo $row['gender'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='gender' value='<?php echo $row['gender'];?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Age:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['age']==NULL){  echo $row['age'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='number' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='age' value='<?php if(isset($age)){echo $age;}?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Country:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['country']==NULL){ echo $row['country'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='country' value='<?php echo $row['country'];?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>City/Town:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['city']==NULL){echo $row['city']; }else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='city' value='<?php echo $row['city'];?>'/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Native languages:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['native_lang']==NULL){echo $row['native_lang'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='native_lang' value='<?php echo $row['native_lang'];?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Learned languages:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['learned_lang']==NULL){echo $row['learned_lang'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='learned_lang' value='<?php echo $row['learned_lang'];?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Learning leanguages:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['learning_lang']==NULL){echo $row['learning_lang'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='learning_lang' value='<?php echo $row['learning_lang'];?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Most favourite language:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
            <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['most_fav_lang']==NULL){echo $row['most_fav_lang'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='most_fav_lang' value='<?php echo $row['most_fav_lang'];?>'/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Best method to learn a language:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
             <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['best_method_to_learn']==NULL){ echo $row['best_method_to_learn'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <textarea class='textar' maxlength="2000" name='best_method_to_learn'><?php echo $row['best_method_to_learn'];?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Why do you learn languages:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
              <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['why_do_you_learn'] == NULL){ echo $row['why_do_you_learn'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <textarea class='textar' maxlength="2000" name='why_do_you_learn'><?php echo $row['why_do_you_learn'];?>
             </textarea>
           </div>
        </div>
          <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>Your most favourite way to practice a language:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
            <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['your_most_fav_way'] == NULL){echo $row['your_most_fav_way'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <textarea class='textar' maxlength="2000" name='your_most_fav_way'><?php echo $row['your_most_fav_way']; ?>
             </textarea>  
           </div>
        </div>
          <div class='box-for-info'>
           <span>If the world would speak one language, it would be:</span>
           <div class='box-data-content'>
           <span class='text-al-center'>
                 <?php if(!$row['one_lang_in_the_world']==NULL){ echo $row['one_lang_in_the_world'];}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <textarea class='textar' maxlength="2000" name='one_lang_in_the_world'><?php echo $row['one_lang_in_the_world']; ?>
             </textarea>  
           </div>
        </div>
```

And as you can see - the code is repeating itself but the row changes. I thought I could save whole lot of code and memory if I would use a loop that would be something like:

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($rows){?>
 <div class='box-for-info'>
     <span>Name:</span>
     <div class='box-data-content'>
        <span class='text-al-center'>
         <?php if(!$row[$rows]==NULL){echo $row['name'];}else{echo '-';}?>
         </span>
         <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='name' value='<?php echo $row[$rows];?>'/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is that I don't really know how to identify rows so I can iterate through them here:

```
$row[$rows]
```

and also here:

```
name='gender'
```

I need with each loop to change the name of a row like: `$row['name']`, `$row['gender']` etc.

How can I transfer my code into a nice little loop? Any help?

Comment: Maybe I explained the question incorrectely - but i dont need to loop through rows! The row result can be ony one! Only one $row['name'], $row['age'] etc. Theres's no need to loop through all $row['age'] because there's only one!  Instead I need to loop throuh different columns of sme row! So istead of writting each time: $row['age'], $row['country'] I want to do domething like: $row[$i], so I need to sort the columns of same row in array and than just chenhe the index; How do I do That?

Comment: Why not use **foreach($row as $key => $value) { var_dump($value);}**

Answer (score 1):

```
This will helpful only replace the array to db array

    <?php
$arr=array('test1','test2','test3');
$row = count($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){?>
 <div class='box-for-info'>
     <span>Name:</span>
         <div class='box-data-content'>
            <span class='text-al-center'>
             <?php if(!$key==NULL){echo $value;}else{echo '-';}?>
             </span>
             <input type='text' class='data-inputs' maxlength="30" name='name' value='<?php echo $value;?>'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It workd but I can't make {echo $value;} this part echo the value of a row!

Comment: So in the case of yur code I need somehow(oh god) to connect two arrays(first: the query - array itself and second = the $arr array) at get the value of a row...

Comment: the use msql_fetch_array() which will return associate array in key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) returns only number of rows in result set, it does not return data.

Use mysqli_fetch_row in while loop to iterate over all rows

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
```

and you don't need any $rows variable. Use

```
var_dump($row)
```

to see the structure of returned data

To loop over all columns in one row use

```
foreach($row as $key => $value) { var_dump($value);}
```

Comment: Can you do this after `mysqli->close()`?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Both mysqli_fetch_row and mysqli_num_rows require active connection.

Comment: Is there a way to take a snapshot to be used later with connection closed?

Comment: I am afraid there is no better way than fetching all results (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

The more typical approach would be like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
    ...stuff with $row["columnname"]...
<?php }
```

You basically get a fresh associative array $row for each row of data and it auto terminates when you run out of data.  No need to refer to an index variable unless you need to create a counter.

Or maybe try something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $colname=>$coldata) {
        echo "<p>";
        echo htmlentities($colname);
        echo " is ";
        echo htmlentities($coldata);
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

...which will iterate through the columns for you by column name as well.  Obviously use $colname and $coldata in your real output--this was just illustrative.  Note the use of htmlentities(), which makes sure that a wayward less-than sign doesn't mess up your html (and helps prevent XSS problems).

Comment: $row["columnname"] ? but how exactely should I refer to a row if it changes with each loop?

Comment: At the top of the loop, you will literally get the whole row of data in $row, so you can do things like if(!$row['one_lang_in_the_world']==NULL) and it will just work as long as you use columns named in the query result.  Don't overthink it--give it a shot.

Comment: Ugh.  Wait.  What does your schema look like?  Is each box above one row and not one column?

Comment: Yes. Only one row - and many columns - and throu this columns I need to iterate

Comment: Edited answer for a column iterator as well.  Hope that's more what you're looking for.